# flutter : how to access/manipulate gridview's cell value

Tags: flutter, gridview

Assuming I have
**items = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]**
and I use GridView.builder, to display it with 3 x 3 configuration.

with a trigger of **onTap/onPress** of button, I want to change a selected cell in that GridView.

for example sake, just +1 on the value 0.

how to achieve this in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

for those who seeks this information

you can use provider and consumer to achieve this.

create a provider class

```
class ItemProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<int> _items = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

  List<int> get items {
    return _items;
  }


  increase(index) {
    _items[index] = _items[index] + 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

then use provider-consumer (i used consumer), make sure you also include it in the provider in common dominator (main.dart)

```
Consumer<ItemProvider>(builder: (context, itemprovider, widget) {
return DragSelectGridView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        gridController: theGridcontroller,
        itemCount: itemprovider.items.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          crossAxisSpacing: 6,
          mainAxisSpacing: 6,
          childAspectRatio: 1,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index, isSelected) => SelectableItemWidget(
          item: itemprovider.mapping[index],
          isSelected: isSelected,
          index: index,
        ),
      );
})
```

and finally, in SelectableItemWidget's class, onTap, u can refer to your methods in ItemProvider class like so

```
class SelectableItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
..
....
...
class _SelectableItemWidgetState extends State<SelectableItemWidget> {
...
....
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ItemProvider>(builder: (context, itemprovider, child) {
     ....
    onTap: () => itemprovider.increase(widget.index),
```